# Inequality for matrix exponential

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-exponential

> Let $A \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ and assume that there is an $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $\langle x, A x \rangle \leq \lambda\langle x,x\rangle$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^n$. Show that $$\|\exp(t A)x\| \leq e^{\lambda t}\lVert x\rVert,\qquad t \geq 0$$

My problem here is that I don't know how to apply the given inequality when starting with $\lVert \exp(tA)x\rVert$. What can I do with that expression so that $A$ is not "bounded" in the exponential and I can use the inequality? Is it a certain property of the norm?

Edit: I have tried to plugin the exponential series:

$$||\exp(tA)x||\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}||A^nx||\leq\dots\leq\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}\lambda^n||x||$$ but I haven't been able to fill out the $\dots$ so far.

Comment: Are you sure that you're not missing something from the question?  Should it be $\langle Ax, Ax \rangle$?  Is $A$ known to be symmetric?

Comment: I am not sure. If the condition included $\langle Ax, Ax\rangle$ I the "$\dots$" would basically fill itself. I will ask the prof.